# Common interface for HTMLElement and HTMLDocument?

Tags: javascript, dom

Some DOM selection methods like getElementsByClassName() are common to HTMLDocument and HTMLElement.

Is there any common interface for inheriting common selection methods? ( as an example Node interface provides some common methods).

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test");

element.getElementsByClassName("test");
```

Comment: element.getElementByClassName("test"); has a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both inherit through the prototype chain from [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node), but it appears that those particular methods aren't defined in a common interface; they appear independently in each of `Element` and `Document`.

```
Object --> Node --> Element --> HTMLElement
             \----> Document --> HTMLDocument
```

Comment: But selection methods are not defined on Node object and these methods are not inherited from Node.

Comment: Oh, you're right; I didn't read carefully enough. That's the inheritance hierarchy, but it appears those selectors appear independently in `Element` and `Document`. An implementation may share underlying logic between the two, but it doesn't appear to me that there's an interface defining that set of methods.

Comment: Correct,if it's not defined on Node that means independent implementation. please modify your answer. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the common methods when it comes to selection:

```
getElementsByClassName
getElementsByTagName
getElementsByTagNameNS
querySelector
querySelectorAll
```

Other methods like `getElementById` are specific only to `document`